# standalone spark: worker didn't show up

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I have 2 question want to know:

This is my code:

```
object Hi {
  def  main (args: Array[String]) {
    println("Sucess")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HI").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val textFile = sc.textFile("src/main/scala/source.txt")
    val rows = textFile.map { line =>
      val fields = line.split("::")
      (fields(0), fields(1).toInt)
    }
    val x = rows.map{case (range , ratednum) => range}.collect.mkString("::")
    val y = rows.map{case (range , ratednum) => ratednum}.collect.mkString("::")
    println(x)
    println(y)
    println("Sucess2")

  }
}
```

Here is some of resault :

```
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://192.168.1.105:4040
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID <driver> on host localhost
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@192.168.1.105:64952/user/HeartbeatReceiver
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 64954
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
15/04/26 16:49:57 INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:64954 with 983.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 64954)
.....
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[4] at map at Hi.scala:25)
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1331 bytes)
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/Users/Winsome/IdeaProjects/untitled/src/main/scala/source.txt:0+23
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1). 1787 bytes result sent to driver
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1) in 13 ms on localhost (1/1)
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 1 (collect at Hi.scala:25) finished in 0.013 s
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
15/04/26 16:49:59 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: collect at Hi.scala:25, took 0.027784 s
1~1::2~2::3~3
10::20::30
Sucess2
```

My first question is : When I check `http://localhost:8080/`
There is no worker. and I can't open `http://192.168.1.105:4040` too
Is is because I use spark standalone?
How to fixed this??

(My environment is MAC,IDE is Intellij)

[image]

My 2nd question is:

```
    val x = rows.map{case (range , ratednum) => range}.collect.mkString("::")
    val y = rows.map{case (range , ratednum) => ratednum}.collect.mkString("::")
    println(x)
    println(y)
```

I thiink these code could be more easily to get x and y (something like this stuff :`rows[range]`,`rows[ratenum]`),But I'm not familiar with scala . 
Could you give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about you first question, but reading your log I see that the worker node lasted 13 ms, so this may be the reason why you haven't see it. Run a longer job and you may see the workers.

About the second question, yes, there is a simpler way to write it that is:

```
val x = rows.map{(tuple) => tuple._1}.collect.mkString("::")
```

because your `RDD` is made of `Tuple` scala objects, which are made of two fields you can access with `_1` and `_2` respectively.

Comment: Thank you. For 1st question,There is no  job in complicated Application ,too .Should I need to set something?

Comment: I don't know what to say about the first question... I had no similar issue when running Spark in standalone way...